# $0 of has no declared type

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

Bison compiler returns me the error $0 of 'routine' has no declared type. I'm trying to print a message declaring a fonction, so I have to print the opening brace before printing the body of the function. I read the doc, and I found a solution coming from that page :[Bison 3.0.4: Actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Actions.html) so I tried to apply it to my problem :

```
fun_decl : 
    type routine fun {end_fonction();};

routine :
    {declare_fonction($0);};
```

I also specified a type for the non terminal 'type' :

```
%type <type_object> type
```

So I don't understand where does my mistake come from.

NB : When I simply associate an empty instruction on the non terminal routine, bison also returns a mistake : "rule useless in parser due to conflicts". Does it mean I can't have multiple empty rules ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a [mid-rule action](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mid_002dRule-Actions.html):

```
fun_decl : 
    type {declare_fonction($1);} fun {end_fonction();};
```

This has the advantage that bison knows the type of `$1`. It never tries to figure out the type of `$0` because it is not possible in the general case.

As discussed in the manual, mid-rule actions can create shift-reduce conflicts. "Marker" (empty) non-terminals, like your `routine`, can also create shift-reduce conflicts, and roughly under the same circumstances. But that will be a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to my problem, I had to specify the type of $0, to let Bison know the size to take in the stack. In my case :

```
routine :
    {declare_fonction($<type_object>0);};
```

Comment: You have to be careful with this. As rici noted, there's a reason Bison does not try to guess at the type of `$0`, namely, that it's not always the same (it depends on how you arrived at the current nonterminal—though if you, or Bison, were to inspect the grammar you could figure out whether it's reliable for your particular grammar). The mid-rule action *is* guaranteed to work since the parser always takes the shift action there.

Comment: I don't understand why, I mean it's written on the bison doc, and 'routine' is only called this way, so as long as I'm using this non terminal carefully, I shouldn't make any error in my opinion.

Comment: Well, yes, as I said "you have to be careful": use the non-terminal such that $0 is always a type_object and has not been overwritten yet.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the type of `routine`:

```
%type <type_object> routine
```

Comment: I think I don't have to, because I never use routine as an argument, $0 refers to 'type'. It works well without it though.